# sql query with group by order by with inner select clause

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is my table relationship.

Users, Roles(Uers roles), Users_map(User is assigned to a team), Team(Different teams), case_inventory

```
Users
TIN Name    Role_id Member_id
123 ABC     40      1   
321 CDE     30      0
678 FGH     40      2
987 XYZ     40      3
087 TYU     40      4

Users_map
tin team
123 1
321 2
678 2
987 2
087 5

Roles:
id role
30  Team President
40  Team Member

Team
id  Name 
1   Geo
2   Math
3   Science
4   Comp Si
5   Hist
```

team_inventory(caseId is the id in team table)

```
teamId  TIN Assigned_to PREPARED
1       789 123         N
2       897 678         Y
3       987 123         Y
4       675 123         Y
2       900 321         Y
5       800 678         Y
```

I am expecting an output as follows:this is based on team from UI. If the selection is Math:

```
Role            Cases   Prepped %Completion
Team President  1       1       100%            <- 1 inventory is assigned to 321 who is a boardpresident
Team Member 2   2       2       100%            <- 2 inventory is assigned to 678 who is a board member whos member id is 2hence team member 2
Team Member 3   0       0       0%              <- math team has another team member (team member 3 - id 987 in users table) but no assignment hence 0 case 0 prepped
Summary         3       3       100%
```

My query looks like this,

```
select
        COALESCE(role,
        'Summary')role,
        SUM(CASE 
            WHEN PREPARED is null THEN 0 
            ELSE 1 
        END)  as cases ,
        SUM(CASE 
            WHEN PREPARED = 'Y' THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END) as prepped,
        round(avg(CASE 
            WHEN PREPARED = 'Y' THEN 100 
            ELSE 0 
        END),
        2)||'%' as comp  
    from
        ( select
            CASE 
                WHEN r.id = 30 THEN r.name 
                ELSE r.name || ' ' || u.member_id 
            END AS role, 
            ti.prepared 
        from
            users u  
        left outer join
            roles r 
                on u.role_id = r.id   
        left outer join
            team_inventory ti   
                on   u.tin = ti.assigned_to  
        left outer join
            roles r 
                on u.role_id = r.id   
        left outer join
            user_map um 
                on  um.tin = u.tin  
        left outer join
            team t
                on ti.team_id = t.id   
        where
            r.id in(
                30,40
            ) 
            and ti.team_id =2 ) 
    group by
        rollup (role);
```

This query works fine but order by is not working with group by . It doesnt have an effect either within the inner select or outer select.
Is there an efficient way to write this query to get the desired output which will also include order by which is team president followed by team members and summary?

Comment: You don't have `order by` in the query. You might try making a sqlfiddle with some sample data so we could have a try at it.

Comment: I think your `case...when` would be much easier to read as `decode` and `nvl2`.  E.g., `sum(nvl2(PREPARED, 1, 0)) cases, sum(decode(PREPARED,'Y',1,0)) prepped ...`.

Comment: I already showed you how to use `grouping(role)` to get the needed ordering in `order by`, when you asked the same question just a couple of days ago. You abandoned that thread - with no follow-up - and opened this new one... NOT COOL.

Comment: @mathguy i am unabl to edit any of the previous ones